# onclick requires several clicks after inserting some text

Tags: javascript, html

I would need some help to understand the behaviour of my code. Let's say there are two pages and you open the second page by clicking a link in the first page, Returning back to the first page happens by onclick="history.go(-1);" function, which works fine. But in case I first insert some text in a div on a second page with getElementById- function the history.go(-1) functions stops working. Or it actually works but requires several clicks.

I have read that it is because of the DOM model is changed, but I don't know how to correct the functionality.
Below is example code of the two pages,

Thanks for helping!

Page 1;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h2>
Please click the link below to open another page.<br>
From that page you should return back here by clicking Back-1 or Back-2.<br><br>
However, if you first click Read comments link, the Back-2 version does not work
or requires several clicks to work.<br><br>

<a href="details.php">Open details</a>
</h2>
</html>
```

Page 2;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #C1BDB0;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>

    <script >
        function getComments(){
            document.getElementById("infotxt").innerHTML = "This is a fake response from Ajax";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  

<ul>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">Back-1</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="history.go(-1);" href="#">Back-2</a></li>    
  <li><a onclick='getComments()' class='active' href='#'>Read comments </a></li>
</ul>

<div>
    <span id="infotxt"></span>
    <br><br>
    <h2>
    From this page you should return back to previous page by clicking 
    Back-1 or Back-2.<br><br>
    However, if you first click Read comments -link, the Back-2 version does 
    not work or requires several clicks (one double + one) to work.<br>
    The Back-1 version works in both cases.
    </h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried go(-2)?

Comment: Sounds like its time to look into building a Single Page Application. State managers help solve these types of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does not solve the problem because in case user have not inserted the text, go(-2) does not work correctly. It however works in case the text was inserted.

Comment: So, if I use some kind of state variable and use go(-1) if text is not inserted and use go(-2) if text was inserted. That way I can solve my problem. Thanks for your comments. I'm happy to hear if there are any other solutions to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `#` that being added to the end of the url once a button is clicked. To get around this, you could alter your `getComments` function like below, and also create an other function for your navigation call as well.

```
function goBack(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    history.go(-1);
}

function getComments(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("infotxt").innerHTML = "This is a fake response from Ajax";
}
```

Also, change your markup to pass in the event object as well like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goBack(event);">Back-2</a>
<a href='#' onclick="getComments(event);" class="active">Read comments</a>
```

`event.preventDefault()` is the line that prevents the url to be changed, by not performing the default click behavior.

Comment: With this change the code works now as expected. Very nice, thank you @dferenc.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.